# Replace only linear term in a polynomial

Tags: replacement

Given a polynomial, for instance `A+A^2+A^3`, how can I replace `A->x`, ending with `x+A^2+A^3`?

**Attempts:**

The problem is I cannot do it without also replacing the higher-order terms. For example, `A+A^2+A^3 /.{A^exp_/;exp==1->x}` does nothing. Another obvious choice, `A+A^2+A^3 /.{A^1->x}`, returns `x+x^2+x^3`. On the other hand, the inverse works: `A+A^2+A^3 /.{A^exp_/;exp!=1->x^exp}` does lead to `A+x^2+x^3`.

This leads to a second question: Why does `A^1` matches any power of `A` but `A^x_/;x==1` matches nothing?

Comment: How would you want to treat constants? eg `1 + A + A^2 + A^3`

Answer (score 6):

What about

```
poly + SeriesCoefficient[poly,{A,0,1}]*(x-A)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
rule = {{b_. Power[c_, d_] :> b Power[c, d], a_. A :> a x}};

A + A^2 + A^3 /. rule
```

> {A^2 + A^3 + x}

---

```
a A + 4 A^2 + A^3 /. rule
```

> {4 A^2 + A^3 + a x}

Answer (score 3):

```
ReplaceAll[w A + x A^2 + y A^3, {p_Power :> p, A -> z}]
```

> ```
> A^2 x + A^3 y + w z
> ```